# Getting IndexOutOfBoundException While iterating Arraylist in for loop

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException while Iterating the Arraylist by using For loop. I knew it why i am getting this exception but i don't the solution to fix this issue.

I have to divide the string based up on the values in the Arraylist. For this i have used the `subString(int startingIndex,int endingIndex)` method.

I am getting exception in this line

```
    String subString = queryString.substring(count.get(i),count.get(i+1));
```

The value of `i` is exceeding the Size of the list.

Code:

```
   String queryString = request.getQueryString();

      Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("check=on");

      Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(queryString);
      ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>();
     while(m1.find())
      {
         count.add(m1.start());

      }

     // Iterating Arraylist

     for (int i = 0; i < count.size() ; i++) {

        String subString = queryString.substring(count.get(i),count.get(i+1));
        out.println("subString:"+ subString);
      }
```

I hope you will understand my ques.

Comment: change for (int i = 0; i < count.size() ; i++) { to for (int i = 0; i < (count.size()-1) ; i++) { otherwise  the count.get(i+1) will cause this

Comment: You have answered your own q, the value of i is exceeding the arraylist because of i+1

Answer (score 0):

You're going from `i = 0` to `i = count.size() - 1` - that is, exactly the size of the array.

However,

```
for (int i = 0; i < count.size() ; i++) {
    String subString = queryString.substring(count.get(i),count.get(i+1));
    out.println("subString:"+ subString);
  }
```

This uses `i+1`, meaning that on the last loop it will go too high, giving you your out-of-bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
String subString = queryString.substring(count.get(i),count.get(i+1));
```

the blurb `count.get(i+1)` will end up trying to fetch past the end of the `ArrayList` since `i` will eventually be equal to the last element index. You might want to change the for-loop to

```
`...; i < count.size()-1 ;...`
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to always query adjacent pairs.

In that case, you need to run until one element before the end of the list, not the actual end (meaning until `count.size() - 1`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count.size() -1 ; i++) {
    String subString = queryString.substring(count.get(i),count.get(i+1));
    out.println("subString:"+ subString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line `String subString = queryString.substring(count.get(i),count.get(i+1));` you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if `i=cont.size()-1` because `count.get(i+1)` will be `count.size()`.

You have to stop at `count.size() -1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count.size()-1 ; i++) {
```